# How to load custom DLS or SoundFonts to Android MIDI

Tags: android, midi, soundfont

I have an application that plays MIDI files through the SONiVOX EAS library.
Is it possible to load my own DLS or SoundFont wavetables into the player and have the library use these sounds for MIDI playback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I change my answer completely, as the [Jet Creator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html) obviously wasn't what you were looking for.

I took a look into the eas library, and found, ([in eas.h](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/sonivox/arm-hybrid-22k/host_src/eas.h))

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * EAS_LoadDLSCollection()
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Purpose: 
 * Downloads a DLS collection
 *
 * Inputs:
 * pEASData             - instance data handle
 * streamHandle         - file or stream handle
 * locator              - file locator
 *      
 * Outputs:
 * 
 *
 * Side Effects:
 * May overlay instruments in the GM sound set
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
EAS_PUBLIC EAS_RESULT EAS_LoadDLSCollection (EAS_DATA_HANDLE pEASData, EAS_HANDLE streamHandle, EAS_FILE_LOCATOR locator);
```

Now this surely indicates that there is a way to load DLS files into the player.
I've never used it though.

Comment: but I'm no using jet player, i'm using the sonivox so directly. any ideads

Comment: thanks for the reference, i tried it but it seems to have no effect on the midi playback - it seems like it uses the same internal gm sound bank as efore. any ideas?

Comment: its seems to work. sort of. The dls is loading but it is not clear how to create the midi file that will actually use it.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this Eli?

Comment: I'm also trying to find out how to do this. Were you able to create the midi file @EliKonky or @Brett?