# Android: Loading Custom Midi Instruments DLS files into Sonivox EAS

Tags: android, audio, midi

I'm creating an Android midi application using the popular [billthefarmer driver package](https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver). With the help of Markus Kauppinen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193250/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-play-midi-notes) thread I was able to make my app generate and control midi events (note on, pause, etc) successfully.

As some of you may know, the default GM1 instruments included with the Sonivox EAS Android library don't sound the greatest. For my app, I desire a way to load custom instruments into the synthesizer, like specific models of a saxophone for example.

I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125911/how-to-load-custom-dls-or-soundfonts-to-android-midi) from 5 years ago of asking how to do the same thing I am. The answer to that question suggests using the EAS_LoadDLSCollection() method in the EAS.h library. Unfortunately, the programmer could only find a way to load custom DLS files into the library, not actually generate the playable instrument's soundfont(wrong term?) which notes can be played through.

Can anyone shed some light on how to load and use custom instruments in Android via it's native Sonivox EAS Midi library?